# How to display this list in different data type?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
List i=new ArrayList();

    i.add("abc");
    i.add("def");
    i.add(61);
    i.add(9);
    i.add(50);
    i.add("ghi");
    i.add("ikh");
    i.add("oihik");
    i.add("oig");
    i.add(243);
    i.add(5);
    i.add(54);

    for (Iterator iterator = new Test123((i.iterator())); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Object object = (Object) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(object);
```

Expected output will be:

String input: `abc def ghi ikh oihik oig`

Integer input: `61 9 50 243 5 54`

I'm new in java and doing my internship in system maintenance and development. I really need some help for this problem.. pleasee help me

---

How about if the list is grouped and i want to filter the Integer output?

The expected output will be:

String input: `abc def ghi ikh oihik oig`

Integer input: `61 9 50 243 5 54`

Integer less than 60 are: 9 50 5 54

Comment: Don't understand your problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: See the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to separate string and integer elements and print them, you can do it like this:

```
List i=new ArrayList();

i.add("abc");
i.add("def");
i.add(61);
i.add(9);
i.add(50);
i.add("ghi");
i.add("ikh");
i.add("oihik");
i.add("oig");
i.add(243);
i.add(5);
i.add(54);

StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder( "String input:");
StringBuilder intBuilder = new StringBuilder( "Integer input:");

for( Object o : i)
{
    if( o instanceof String)
    {
        strBuilder.append( " ");
        strBuilder.append( o);
    }
    else if( o instanceof Integer)
    {
        intBuilder.append( " ");
        intBuilder.append( o);
    }
}

System.out.println( strBuilder.toString());
System.out.println( intBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: you could actually change instanceof integer to instanceof Number to cater for decimals too

Comment: Thank you so much. u helped me a lot and something new in java uoyilmaz  and @user3138997

Answer (score 0):

You can test each item in the list with `instanceof Class`.

- `instanceof String` returns true if the item of your list is of `String`
- `instanceof Double` returns true if the item of your list is of `Double`
- `instanceof Number` returns true if the item of your list is any of `Integer`, `Double` etc.

This is a very simple and straightforward way using `Stream` and `lambda expression`. Finally extract the needed `String` with `replaceAll()` method used on the List's String representation.

```
List<String> listString = (List<String>) i.stream()
     .filter(t -> t instanceof String).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Number> listNumber = (List<Number>) i.stream()
     .filter(t -> t instanceof Number).collect(Collectors.toList());

String str = listString.toString().replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("[\\[.\\].\\s+]", " ");
String num = listNumber.toString().replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("[\\[.\\].\\s+]", " ");

System.out.println(str); // prints: abc def ghi ikh oihik oig
System.out.println(num); // prints: 61 9 50 243 5 54
```

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. i do really wanna try for stream method. but..i'm using eclipse which not support for java.util.stream. i think it does not support for it.

Comment: I work with Eclipse and it definetly supports Stream. You anly need Java 8.

Comment: okay I see. I didn't know. Thank youuu @Nikolas Charalambidis

Comment: Welcome. If one of answers helped you to solve your issue, please mark it as accepted to avoid this question to be longer unanswered.